# Trying to get rid of a part of a string (used as file path) in order to go back a directory

Tags: php, string, split, directory

My problem is as follows. My PHP code relies on a string to determine a file directory, by removing the last part of the path.  I want to go back a directory. Consider the following example:

Original Input:

```
$dir = "this/is/a/files/location"
```

Desired Output:

```
$dir = "this/is/a/files"
```

Basically, I need it to remove everything to the right of the first "/".

Thank you so much for your help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) along with [strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

```
$dir = "this/is/a/files/location";

$dir = substr($dir, 0, strrpos( $dir, '/'));
```

Output:- https://eval.in/949366

Answer (score 1):

This Might Help

```
$dir = "this/is/a/files/location"; 
$popped = explode('/',$dir);
array_pop($popped);
$dir = implode('/',$popped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method, using `str_replace` and `basename`

```
    $dir = "this/is/a/files/location";
    echo str_replace( '/' . basename( $dir ), '', $dir );
```

output:

```
this/is/a/files
```

update [ 01.04.2019 ]
Having just been given a `plus one` I looked again at this and have an additional snippet to offer ~ it seems to me much easier than my previous offering - `chdir('../')`

```
    /* where did we start off? */
    printf('Current directory: %s<br />', getcwd() );

    /* go up a level */
    chdir('../');

    /* where are we now? */
    printf('Current directory: %s', getcwd() );
```